# Airflow server is not running in daemon mode

Tags: daemon, airflow

Airflow webserver is still running in the foreground with this command "airflow webserver -D". I am not sure if I am missing something here? Although, airflow scheduler -D is working properly

Answer (score 6):

remove `airflow-webserver.err` and `airflow-webserver-monitor.pid` from AIRFLOW_HOME directory.

helped me