# Error with Apache Airflow while running airflow webserver as daemon

Tags: airflow, webserver, daemon

I am running Apache Airflow 2.3.0 on an Oracle Linux machine, when I run the commands on 2 different terminals (commands `airflow scheduler` and `airflow webserver`), everything works fine. But, when I try to run the services as daemons (commands `airflow scheduler -D` and `airflow webserver -D`), only the scheduler command works. The webserver command generates the following error.

[image]

I configured airflow (and therefore the `webserver_conf.py` file) to work via OAuth authentication, added my own provider and extended the `AirflowSecurityManager` class so it can validate the new provider. As I mentioned before if I run the services normally everything works fine (even the authentication to login into the app). I configured the `webserver_conf.py` file following the Apache [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/webserver.html), here is the configuration I made to the `webserver_conf.py` file.

```
from airflow.www.security import AirflowSecurityManager

class BaseSecurityManagerTQ(AirflowSecurityManager):
    def get_oauth_user_info(self, provider, resp):
        if provider == "TQ":
            me = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('/connect/userinfo')
            data = me.json()
            ans = {
                "username": "tq_" + data.get('name', ""),
                "email": data.get("email", ""),
            }
            return ans
        else:
            return {}

FAB_SECURITY_MANAGER_CLASS = "webserver_config.BaseSecurityManagerTQ"
```

I tried importing the new security module using the `importlib` library, but it didn't work. I also tried these solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476246/issues-running-airflow-scheduler-as-a-daemon-process),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737229/airflow-server-is-not-running-in-daemon-mode) and they didn't work either.

Any advice on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already managed to solve.I had to add the folder where `webserver_config.py` file is located to the PYTHON_PATH. Also, add a `__init__.py` file to be able to import the module.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue - could you share your service file? how did you specify the PYTHON_PATH in there?